# Draw method not working

Tags: java, android

So i've started learnin android studio game development from this series: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rliwg0sELJo and i can't seem to find the reason why my draw method isn't working. i triple checked my code and the video and ran some tests to try and find my error but ended up blank.

please keep in mind i'm new to stackoverflow and programming so if you see any ways i can improve on stuff like formatting i'd love to hear it

MainActivity:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new GamePanel(this));
}
}
```

GamePanel:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;


public class GamePanel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private MainThread thread;

private RectPlayer player;
private Point playerPoint;

public GamePanel(Context context){
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    thread=new MainThread(getHolder(),this);
    player = new RectPlayer(new Rect(100,100,200,200), Color.rgb(255,0,0));
    playerPoint=new Point(150,150);
    setFocusable(true);
}
@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder,int format,int width,int height){

}
@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
    thread = new MainThread(getHolder(),this);

    thread.setRunning(true);
    thread.start();
}
@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    boolean retry = true;
    while(retry){
        try{
            thread.setRunning(false);
            thread.join();
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
        retry=false;
    }
}
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        playerPoint.set((int)event.getX(),(int)event.getY());
    }
    return true;
    //return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public void update(){
    player.update(playerPoint);
    System.out.println(playerPoint.x);
    System.out.println(playerPoint.y);
}
@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    super.draw(canvas);

    canvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

    player.draw(canvas);
}
}
```

MainThread:

```
package com.example.student.game_core1;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;

public class MainThread extends  Thread {
public static final int MAX_FPS=30;
private double averageFPS;
private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
private GamePanel gamePanel;
private  boolean running;
public static Canvas canvas;

public void setRunning(boolean running){
    this.running=running;
}


public MainThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder,GamePanel gamePanel){
    super();
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    this.gamePanel = gamePanel;
}

@Override
public void run(){

    long startTime;
    long timeMillis;
    long waitTime;
    int frameCount=0;
    long totalTime=0;
    long targetTime=1000/MAX_FPS;

    while (running){
        startTime=System.nanoTime();
        canvas=null;
        try{
            canvas=this.surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder){
                this.gamePanel.update();
                this.gamePanel.draw(canvas);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally {
            if(canvas!=null){
                try{
                    surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
                }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
        timeMillis=(System.nanoTime()-startTime)/1000000;
        waitTime=targetTime - timeMillis;
        try{
            if(waitTime>0)
                this.sleep(waitTime);
        }catch(Exception e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        totalTime+=System.nanoTime()-startTime;
        frameCount++;
        if(frameCount==MAX_FPS){
            averageFPS=1000/(totalTime/frameCount/1000000);
            frameCount=0;
            totalTime=0;
            System.out.println(averageFPS);
        }
    }
}
}
```

RectPlayer:

```
package com.example.student.game_core1;

import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.Point;
import android.graphics.Rect;

public class RectPlayer implements GameObject {

private Rect rectangle;
private int color;

public RectPlayer(Rect rectangle, int color){
    this.rectangle=rectangle;
    this.color=color;
}

@Override
public void draw(Canvas canvas){
    Paint paint=new Paint();
    paint.setColor(color);
    canvas.drawRect(rectangle,paint);
}

@Override
public void update(){

}

public void update(Point point){
    rectangle.set((point.x)-(rectangle.width()/2),(point.y)-(rectangle.height()/2),(point.x)+(rectangle.width()/2),(point.y)+(rectangle.height()/2));
}

public Rect getRectangle() {
    return rectangle;
}
}
```

Comment: What I know method signature is `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` with D capital and not just `draw(Canvas canvas)`

Answer (score 0):

If im not wrong you are using Canvas, trying to `draw` your item with `draw()` method.

It seems that you need to use another method (**onDraw(Canvas)**):

Draw your graphics in a Canvas object. To use this option, you pass your canvas to the appropriate class' **onDraw(Canvas)** method. You can also use the drawing methods in Canvas. This option also puts you in control of any animation.

If you need more info about canvas, just go here --> https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

Comment: well i tried changing the draw() to onDraw() but the rectangle still isn't drawn